# Verpatch.exe error

Tags: windows, versioning, qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to add new version resource string to .exe file using verpatch.

I need to add new sting to version resource as I am creating test connector to Qlikview. For QlikView and Qlik Sense to be able to recognize an .exe file as a connector, the file version information resource must include the property “QlikView Connector”.

I am developing my connector with Visual Studio and this command is run as a post build command and build ends with error. I also tried to run it from command line with same result:

`C:\verpatch>verpatch.exe C:\QV_temp\QVTestConnector.exe  /s "QlikView Connector" "Qv Test Connector"
Exception in ParseBinaryVersionResource
Error in ParseBinaryVersionResource
error parsing version info from the file
Some of actions failed, exiting`

I have also tried different versions on verpatch.exe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The example that Qlik gives on [their documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview-developer/12.0/Subsystems/QVXSDKAPI/Content/Making-connector-recognizable-by-QlikView.htm) does not seem to work with the version of `verpatch.exe` that ships with QVX SDK 2.1.

I resolved this error by updating to a newer version from [CodePlex](https://ddverpatch.codeplex.com/releases).

**Edit:**
verpatch seems to have moved to https://github.com/pavel-a/ddverpatch/releases

Answer (score 1):

Please see [documentation](http://ddverpatch.codeplex.com/documentation). After /s should go "description".
If it has problem reading existing version resource, try to rewrite it completely with /va. So, do something like:

verpatch your.exe 1.0.0.0 /va /s desc "QlikView Connector" /s product "Qv Test Connector"

If you can share the problematic exe with the author of verpatch (on Codeplex), he may provide a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't set properties on my executable with any version of `verpatch` - because I had a different codepage in the resource strings.

I would recommend rather using the Python package  [pe-tools](https://github.com/avast/pe_tools) ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pe-tools/)), which has a nicely documented command `peresed` that does this ([docs](https://github.com/avast/pe_tools#resource-editor)).

You can also set specific version-info fields or set resource entries to the contents of a file:

`peresed filename.exe -V "QlikView Connector=Qv Test Connector"`

I have run this command successfully, but not verified whether the properties were set - but other properties like `FileDescription` are set correctly.